# the characteristic impedance leakage inductor and lump capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply

In a flyback converter, how is the characteristic impedance of the leakage inductor and lumped capacitor derived to be \$Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{L_{LEAK}}{C_{LUMP}}}\$?

[image]

Comment: You may get better answers if you add more context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

\$Z_0\$ is the surge impedance of an LC circuit.  This is impedance seen by the  initial transient current.  [Here is](https://pdhonline.com/courses/e493/e493content.pdf) a good link to start on transients.

Allan Greenwood’s [Electrical Transients in Power Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8126527293) has couple great chapters on transients like this and is relatively inexpensive.